# saltstack pillar does not follow the norm of using init.sls with include statements

Tags: salt-stack

When defining saltstack states, you are allowed to structure subdirectories, and within those subdirectories, one can create `init.sls` files which carry the `include` clause that points to other `.sls` files.  I am trying the same thing when defining the Pillar, and it seems that pillars don't look for init.sls files under the specified directories, nor they seem to care for the `include` clause.

Here is an example:

```yaml
#/srv/pillar/top.sls
base:
  '*':
    - dir1.dir2
    - dir1.dir5
```

```yaml
#/srv/pillar/dir1/dir2/init.sls
include:
  - .users
  - .passwords
```

`/srv/pillar/dir1/dir2` has the following files

```
/srv/pillar/dir1/dir2/users.sls
/srv/pillar/dir1/dir2/passwords.sls
```

```yaml
#/srv/pillar/dir1/dir5/init.sls
include:
  - .addresses
  - .names
```

`/srv/pillar/dir1/dir5` has the following files

```
/srv/pillar/dir1/dir5/addresses.sls
/srv/pillar/dir1/dir5/names.sls
```

In this example, it may not be trivial about DRY - but when things become larger, it would be more ideal to have definitions that permit for `include` instead now one would have to write the file as follows:

```yaml
#/srv/pillar/top.sls
base:
  '*':
    - dir1.dir2.users
    - dir1.dir2.passwords
    - dir1.dir2.names
    - dir1.dir5.addresses
```

Am I missing something - any suggestions on how to achieve what I'm reflecting on this use case?

Comment: Pillar includes work fine for me, exactly as you've written them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the pillar's top file is meant to accomplish this. Pillar was designed to provide key and value to a machine that is allowed to see it. It has no concept of including others.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you describe is possible. As described in [SaltStack  Docu](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/pillar/index.html#including-other-pillars) you can include pillars in other pillars. And also a `init.sls` (see [Pillar Walkthrough](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/pillar.html#more-complex-data)) is possible. So I do not see why you should'n do it exactly how you described it. In fact i just did it in the same way and it works!